# Golang equivalent of openssl_public_decrypt from php

Tags: php, go, openssl

I have a pem file and a public key hard-coded in php script. That script uses

`openssl_public_decrypt(file_get_contents($this->licenseFilePath), $decrypted, self::PUBKEY)`

I'd like to rewrite that script with golang. What could be a **go** alternative to **php** openssl_public_decrypt? I have no access to the private key so I cannot change the encryption logic.

Comment: Choose the [crypto package](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/#pkg-subdirectories) for your key type and then pick the appropriate Verify* function in that package.

Comment: crypto/rsa has only (public key encryption)/(private key decryption) but I need the opposite direction

Comment: Only because your (or rather, PHP's) terminology is off. What you want to do is to verify a [digital signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) of a license file. As Peter wrote, there are various Verify* functions. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: Sorry. I do not want just to verify the signature of license. I want to read the license parameters as   php openssl_public_decrypt does. What is wrong in my question? If one does not like php I guess that is a matter of taste. I'll be very thankful for any example how to use    Verify* functions instead of openssl_public_decrypt

Comment: The problem is described here https://topic.alibabacloud.com/a/golang-private-key-encrypt-public-key-decrypt_1_38_30920103.html. But that solution does not work for me

Comment: Maybe you should start out what openssl_public_decrypt actually does. Seems like _a lot_ is hidden by that function.

Comment: I agree with Markus now but where could I read what openssl_public_decrypt actually does internally?